# Install Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

All my life i use Windows. 
I saw a freind using Ubuntu. 
It's my first time in Ubuntu and i'm looking for a tutorial: What should i do after install Ubuntu 13.04?
Thanks for your help.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link can help you,
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-13-04